# Why map is not showing current location if user enabled location at run time on splash screen

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I am wondering why Map is not showing current location if user enabled location at run time at the splash screen. Current location is showing if location is enabled already.

**SplashScreen**`

```
  String status = null;
Bundle bundle = null;
StartLocationAlert startLocationAlert;
protected static final int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 1001;
GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
    googleApiClient = getInstance();
    bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Boolean b1=    locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    LocationManager locationManager1 = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Boolean b2=locationManager1.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    final StartLocationAlert startLocationAlert=new StartLocationAlert(this);

    if (!b1&&!b2) {
        displayDialogloctaion();
    } else {
        startActivityThread();
    }
}
public void startActivityThread(){
    final Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();
            try {
                sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                Intent intent = null;
                boolean loggedIn = false;
                SharedPreferences w = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                SharedPreferences.Editor share = w.edit();
                loggedIn = (w.getBoolean("loggedIn", loggedIn));
                System.out.println("logged in " + loggedIn);
                if (loggedIn) {
                    intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, TestNavigationFragments.class);
                } else {
                    intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, Login.class);
                }
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
    thread.start();
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == -1) {
            final Thread thread = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    super.run();
                    try {
                        sleep(4000);
                        finish();
                        startActivityThread();                         
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
            thread.start();
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}
public  GoogleApiClient getInstance(){
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
    return mGoogleApiClient;
}
public void displayDialogloctaion(){
    Log.e("settingsrequest","Comes");
    LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);
    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
            .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
    builder.setAlwaysShow(true);

    PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
            LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(googleApiClient, builder.build());
    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
            final Status status = result.getStatus();
            final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
            switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:

                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:

                    try {
                        status.startResolutionForResult(SplashScreen.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        Log.e("Applicationsett",e.toString());
                    }

                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                    Toast.makeText(SplashScreen.this, "Location is Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    break;
            }
        }
    });

}
```

**Map Fragment**

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googlemap)).getMapAsync(this);
    ((TestNavigationFragments)getActivity()).dismissdialog();

}


    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        vw = inflater.inflate(R.layout.neib_map, container, false);
        atvPlaces = (EditText) vw.findViewById(R.id.searchAutoComplete);
    final ListView listView = (ListView) vw.findViewById(R.id.list_pred);
        atvPlaces.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            final int DRAWABLE_LEFT = 0;
            final int DRAWABLE_TOP = 1;
            final int DRAWABLE_RIGHT = 2;
            final int DRAWABLE_BOTTOM = 3;
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if(event.getRawX() >= (atvPlaces.getRight() - atvPlaces.getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_RIGHT].getBounds().width())) {
                    atvPlaces.setText("");
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

  ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googlemap)).getMapAsync(this);
        MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());
        markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getActivity().getBaseContext());
        locationManager =
            (LocationManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if(!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) ||
            !locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Location Services Not Active");
        builder.setMessage("Please enable Location Services and GPS");
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS), 1);

            }
        });
        Dialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        alertDialog.show();
        }
        settingLoc();
        atvPlaces.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }
            @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            GetPlaces getPlaces = new GetPlaces();
            String check = atvPlaces.getText().toString();
            if (check.trim().isEmpty()) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please enter address to search", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            } else {

                getPlaces.execute(check);
                listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

        }
            @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
            class GetPlaces extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<String>> {
            private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            @Override

            protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... args) {
                ArrayList<String> predictionsArr = new ArrayList<String>();

                try {
                    URL googlePlaces = new URL(

                            "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input="
                                    + URLEncoder.encode(args[0].toString(),
                                    "UTF-8")
                                    + "&types=geocode&language=en&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyCdPiK8-58hI2fnlfHwsCuRZKWwpB1CGbA");

                    URLConnection tc = googlePlaces.openConnection();

                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(tc.getInputStream()));

                    String line;
                    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

                    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line);
                    }

                    JSONObject predictions = new JSONObject(sb.toString());

                    JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(predictions
                            .getString("predictions"));

                    for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);

                        predictionsArr.add(jo.getString("description"));
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {

                } catch (JSONException e) {

                }

                return predictionsArr;

            }
                @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {

                Log.d("YourApp", "onPostExecute : " + result.size());

                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, result);// show the list view as texts


                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        atvPlaces.setText((String) listView.getAdapter().getItem(position));

                    }

                });
                listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity().getBaseContext());
                        List<Address> addresses = null;

                        try {
                            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName((String) listView.getAdapter().getItem(position), 3);

                            atvPlaces.setText((String) listView.getAdapter().getItem(position));
                        } catch (IOException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        if (addresses != null && !addresses.equals(""))
                            search(addresses);
                        listView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }


                });
                }

        }

    });
    final Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Buyer.class);
    Button sendButton = (Button) vw.findViewById(R.id.button_nk);
    sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                      @Override
                                      public void onClick(View v) {
                                          if(latLng!=null){
                                              String pin1="110092";
                                              if(pin1.equalsIgnoreCase(pin)){
                                                  Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Buyer.class);
                                                  String sendMessage = "hello world";
                                                  intent.putExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE", latLng + "");
                                                  startActivity(intent);
                                              }
                                              else{
                                                  Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Sorry, We don't serve this location yet " ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                              }
                                          }
                                          else{
                                              Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Please wait... or touch Address in the menu" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                          }
                                          }

                                  }
    );
    return vw;
}



private Location getLastKnownLocation() {
    Location bestLocation = null;
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Activity.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        List<String> providers = locationManager.getProviders(true);
        for (String provider : providers) {
            Location l = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            if (l == null) {
                continue;
            }
            if (bestLocation == null || l.getAccuracy() < bestLocation.getAccuracy()) {

                bestLocation = l;
            }
        }
    }
    return bestLocation;
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 2000: {

            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    comeCurrent();

                } else {
                }
                return;
            }}
    }
}

protected void search(List<Address> addresses) {
    Address address = (Address) addresses.get(0);
    latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
    addressText = String.format(
            "%s, %s",
            address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address
                    .getAddressLine(0) : "", address.getCountryName());
    markerOptions   = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title(addressText);
    googleMap.clear();
    googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
    Geocoder geocoder;
    List<Address> addresses1;
    geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity(), Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        addresses1 = geocoder.getFromLocation(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude(), 1); // Here 1 represent max location result to returned, by documents it recommended 1 to 5
        pin = addresses1.get(0).getPostalCode();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public    void settingLoc(){
    if(status!= ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ 
        int requestCode=10;
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, getActivity(), requestCode);
        dialog.show();

    }else { 
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            comeCurrent();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "please grant the permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 2000);
        }
    }
}
protected void comeCurrent(){
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    Location location = getLastKnownLocation();
    if (location != null) {
        onLocationChanged(location);
    }
}


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged (Location location) {
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
       if(googleMap!=null)  {
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Marker"));
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(16));
            Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
            List<Address> addresses = null;
            try {
                addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (addresses.size() > 0)
                atvPlaces.setText(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
       }
    }

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
                String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
                Location location = getLastKnownLocation();

                if (location != null) {
                    onLocationChanged(location);
                }

            }else {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "please grant the permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                        new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 2000);

            }

        }
    }
}




@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    this.googleMap=googleMap;

    Location myLocation = getLastKnownLocation();

    if (myLocation == null) {

        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext() , "your location is NULL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
        double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Marker"));
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(16));

        ((TestNavigationFragments)getActivity()).dismissdialog();
        Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getActivity(), Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses = null;
        try {
            addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
            pin=addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();


            StringBuffer  addressAsString  = new StringBuffer("");
            if(!addresses.isEmpty()){
                for (int i = 0; i < addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++)
                    addressAsString.append(addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(i) + " ");

            }
            String adrs=addressAsString.toString();


            int len=adrs.length();
            if(pin==null){

            if(len>7){
                pin = adrs.substring(len -7, len - 1);
            }
            }
            if(len>34)
            atvPlaces.setText(adrs.substring(0,34).concat("..."));
            else
                atvPlaces.setText(adrs.concat("..."));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

everything is working fine if location is enabled already but not if user enabled at run time.
any ideas?

Comment: You might want to check this documentation - [Request runtime permissions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/location#request_runtime_permissions). If your app targets API level 23 or later, you can use the new permissions model. If your app supports the new permissions model and the device is running Android 6.0 (Marshmallow) or later, the user does not have to grant any permissions when they install or upgrade the app.

Comment: For more code samples and best practices for Android runtime permissions, see the documentation for the [Android permissions model](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/runtime-permissions.html).

Comment: @Mr.Rebot i have already asked for run time permission in my code. some times it is working fine and some time it does not i am wondering why the same code behave like this.

Comment: have you tried using their sample code and tested if the behavior is the same?

Comment: ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 2000);..yes and behaviour is same  i am not getting why onRequestPermissionResult() method is not getting called.